# Backbone.Model. Replace attributes hash

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Is there any `options` for `set` method or any other way to replace the current attributes of the model with ones provided?
Here is what I want:

```
var instance = new Backbone.Model();

instance.set({foo: 1});
instance.set({bar: 2}, {replace: true}); //just for example

console.log(instance.toJSON()); //returns {bar: 2}
```

Comment: Just doing a set again will overwrite the previous value. It's just like setting a variable. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: I need to replace one attributes hash with another. So if I have '{foo:1}' as attributes of the model, passing '{bar: 2}' should remove all previous attributes ('{foo:1}' in our case) and set '{bar:2}' as new attributes hash. Is it clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for this: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-clear

```
instance.clear().set({bar: 2});
```

Comment: 'instance.clear({bar: 2});' is not working actually.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear just one attribute, you can use

`instance.unset('foo').set({bar:2})`